# Скачивание и сохранение файла

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который вызываю в новом потоке:

```
private void downloadFile() {
    try {
        URL u = new URL("http://192.168.0.103:8080/api/v1/test/123.jpg");
        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());
        byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
        FileOutputStream fos = getContext().openFileOutput("123.jpg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Сервер отдаёт файл с Content-Type'ом `application/force-download`

В стактрейсе ошибок нет, но и файла тоже нет, где он может храниться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняет в каталоге, путь на который возвращается методом `context.getFilesDir()`.

Если метод не перегружен, то это каталог `/data/data/[app package]/files`